# When debugging with Xcode, is there way to see a value of property when mouse cursor on it in code?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I don't understand why, even on Xcode 6, I need to click on `self`, search the property, and only then see the value.
If the object have 100 properties it's very annoying.

I'm searching for simple solution that when I set my mouse cursor on `self.someproperty`,
above "`someproperty`" I will see the value of it, in any case, `NSString`, `NSArray`, Etc.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean in the debugger?

Comment: I mean where you set the breakpoints in the actually code that execute. the implementation class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's presumably because the "properties" you're hovering above are not really variables. They are syntactic sugar for accessor methods (that generally reference a backing instance variable, but not necessarily so). These accessor methods, the getter and setter, were either synthesized for you, or you may have manually implemented your own custom methods. For more information about declared properties, see [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DeclaredProperty.html) discussion in Apple's *Core Competencies* document or [Properties Encapsulate an Object's Value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2) in the *Programming with Objective-C* document.

Consider the `foo` property below. You cannot hover over references to `self.foo` and see what you were expecting. But, if you hover over the instance variable (ivar) that backs the property, you may:

[image]

(As an aside, note that the reference to `self.foo = ...` above does not reference the `foo` getter method, but actually calls the setter method `setFoo`. So, it seems like a non-trivial exercise to have the IDE debugger recognize that by hovering over that "property" while execution is paused there, but realize you want to call the getter to see the value rather than calling the setter that line of code actually references.)

Anyway, back to the IDE, you can also twist open `self`, you'll see it there, too:

[image]

These techniques are imperfect (sometimes the debugger gets confused), but hopefully this illustrates the basic UI.

I gather you would like it to call the accessor method when you hover over the property name. Does that mean you also want it to call any random method that the mouse happens to hover over, too? In a purely functional language, this notion seems a little more plausible, but it seems dangerous in the procedural languages where any method could conceivably change a state variable and have some unintended consequence. I would have thought that if you contemplate a feature like this, it should require some something more affirmative action than merely hovering over it.

Anyway, if you really want this feature, file a "feature request" at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I still think that what Microsoft Visual Studio did in 2004 or less,
Apple XCode can do in 2015.

the hovering can trigger and call the property only after 0.2 second when mouse is not moved to prevent triggering unwanted actions.

99% of the properties getters need to only return value and not change the state. that what are methods for.

If the property do something more then return the value, it's the developer responsibilty to understand that in easy or the hard way.

btw, even popping the ivar without calling properties is better then searching the property after self

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the logging functionality of *lldb* right in the console, it's a huge help:

In the right part of your *Debug area* you have the *Console* (that's also where all `NSLog` output goes to).

In the *Console* you can just use the command `po` (*print object*) and `print` to print the value of a variable.

[image]

Comment: well, that's not possible in xcode :/ you can go and file a radar for it so that apple will maybe implement in a future version

Comment: can you change a variable in the console?